# Struts2 <s:iterator iterate value pass in the Another class methods getUserIdById()

Tags: java, struts2

**JSP page:**

```xml
<s:iterator value="classes" status="userStatus">
  <tr>
    <td><s:property value="classTitle" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="viewOrder" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="createdBy" /></td>
    <td><s:date name="createdDate" format="dd-MMM-yyyy"/></td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-green5" value="Manage Sections" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-blue5" value="Edit" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-red5" value="Delete" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

**User logic class:**

```java
public class UserMasterLogic {
    private Session session;
    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public UserMasterLogic() {
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        this.session = factory.openSession();
    }

    public String getUserIdById(int id) {
        UserMaster user = null;
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            user = (UserMaster) session.get(Class.class, id);
        } catch (HibernateException h) {
            System.out.println(h);
        }

        return user.getUserId();
    }
}
```

Now I want to property `createdBy` value pass into `getUserIdById()` method and return value display on the table row.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Nor do I understand a method named `getUserIdById`, wouldn't it make more sense to return a user, not the user id you presumably passed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call some method from JSP page then just call it like so:

```
<s:property value="getUserIdById(createdBy)" />
```

**Update**

The proper way of doing that is to inject your `UserMasterLogic` to your action class and then  if you want to call it from JSP:

```
<s:property value="userMasterLogic.getUserIdById(createdBy)" />
```

Comment: Please explain me how can i create an object of UserMasterLogic Class.

Comment: Do you want to create instance of UserMasterLogic in JSP?

Comment: Thankyou, i solved it with your help. Thanks once again Aleksandr M